# Label all components of BoxWhiskerChart with corresponding data

Tags: plotting, legending, charts

I work with `BoxWhiskerChart`s at the moment. They code looks like this:

```
data = RandomInteger[5, 50];
chart = BoxWhiskerChart[{data},
{{"MedianMarker", 1, Black},{"MeanMarker", 1, White}, {"Outliers"}},
ChartLabels -> Placed[{"data"}, Above]]
```

Now I would like to label the whiskers, both markers (mean and median), and the minimum/maximum of the box with the corresponding values. In the end it should look similar to this (quick and dirty) Excel example:

[image]

What I want is circled red in the picture. I do not need to label each and every data point. How can I accomplish that with Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) to add labels at desired positions:

```
ClearAll[cef]
cef[df_: "BoxWhisker"][off_: 5] := Module[{x = #[[1]],
   q = Quartiles @ #2, m = Round[Mean @ #2, .1], minmax = MinMax@#2}, 
 {ChartElementDataFunction[df][##], Darker @ Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"], 
  FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> Medium, 
  Text[m, Offset[{-off, 0}, {x[[1]], m}], {1, 0}], 
  Text[#, Offset[{off, 0}, {x[[2]], #}], {-1, 0}] & /@ q, 
  Text[#, Offset[{-off, 0}, {x[[2]], #}], {-1, 0}] & /@ minmax}] &
```

**Examples:**

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{data}, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Black}, {"MeanMarker", 1,
    White}, {"Outliers"}}, ChartElementFunction -> cef[][]]
```

[image]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{data, 1 + data}, {2 + data, 3 + data}},
 {{"MedianMarker", 1, Black}, {"MeanMarker", 1, White}, {"Outliers"}}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cef["GlassBoxWhisker"][],  BarSpacing -> {Large, Large}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. Quick note for other users like me since it took me some minutes: of course you have to adjust the rounding parameter (`m = Round[Mean @ #2, .1]`) to your data. Im working with quite small numbers which made it look like it is messing with the plot range.